# Error with turntable render out of Blender and Davinci Resolve

Tags: davinci-resolve, blender

I made a simple turntable animation in blender and while the file runs seamless as a loop when playing back in any video player, once I bring it into resolve then render it out again, it seems to add a frame or something as it pauses between loops in any video player, the same 60fps 1920 by 1080 screen size is used and the output file is around the same size as the original, it seems to be an issue with Davinci resolve itself but have been playing all day trying to find out why with no results, if anyone can point to what may be happening id be grateful, thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a frame zero vs frame 1 issue?  Blender sometimes starts at frame zero, and after effects starts at frame1?

Comment: I dont think it matters as the original clip loops perfectly, once loaded into davinci to export again seems to loose or gain a frame and has a pause between looping, been through every single option and nothing seems to fix it, maybe its a bug

Comment: So, ive found a work around and a potential issue thats causing it, read a post about i-frames and causing a glitch because sometimes davinci skips them or something, dont quite understand but I rendered this time as Tiff images from davinci then loaded them back into blender to render as MP4 and the glitch is gone, so its definitely a davinci issue thats known about, just thought id add this in case anyone else runs into the issue

Comment: you should add it as an answer with steps if you can - you're allowed to answer your own Qs if you find a good solution - with a link to the place you found it